# Use case of Glass Pane vs. Layered Pane

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane, glasspane

I've always been a little fuzzy on the difference between the glass pane and a layered pane.  Is the glass pane essentially just "the very top layer of the root pane," or does it behave differently?  When would you use a layered pane instead of the glass pane?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are two different things:

- the *layered pane* is the destination of all the contents that are added or shown inside a `JFrame`. For example, every normal component like `JLabels`, `JTextFields`, `JTable` etc.. in addition it implictly handles z-ordering of elements that are added to it so it can handles popup menus, or drag and drop effects: this because a popup menu is added to the layered pane with a z higher than the normal components, with the final effect to stay on top of other things. See [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#layeredpane) to understand the behaviour better.
- the *glass pane* is an optional layer that is hidden by default and stays in any case on top of the *layer pane*. So basically everything you draw onto the glass pane will be always visible: you can think of it as a trasparent sheet that is applied on the top of a normal `JFrame` that you can choose to use you need special effects.

Both the *layered pane* and the *glass pane* are placed on the *root pane* that is the basis from which every frame is built up.

Comment: Can you add `JLabels`, `JTexFields`, `JTable` etc. to the glass pane? Or is it just to draw stuff directly on it?